# Working with multiple Scala Futures

Tags: scala, akka, future, async-await

I've more than one `Future`.

```
val actor1 : Future[ActorRef] = createActorA()
val actor2 : Future[ActorRef] = createActorB() 
...
...
...
```

Now I need to extract the `ActorRef`s from all these futures so that I can use them to create a `Router`.

```
val routees = Vector[ActorRef](actor1, actor2, .....)
val router = system.actorOf(Props.empty.withRouter(
  RoundRobinRouter(routees = routees)))
```

I can call `Await` on each of these `Future`s to get the `ActorRef`. Is there is a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Future.sequence` with `foreach`:

```
Future.sequence(Vector(
  createActorA(),
  createActorB() // and so on
)) foreach { routees =>
  val router = system.actorOf(Props.empty.withRouter(
    RoundRobinRouter(routees = routees)))
  // do something with router
}
```

`Future.sequence` takes a collection of futures and returns a future holding a collection with the result of those futures, in this case it returns `Future[Vector[ActorRef]]`. We then invoke `foreach` on this future to attach a handler to the completion of this future. This gives us access to the collection (the `routees`) and we create the needed router. We can continue to do further processing in the function passed to foreach.

Comment: This is a good option (+1). But I need to pass the `router` to another `actor` so that it send messages to the `router` instead of individual actors. So I don't want to put all the complicated logic inside the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use for-comprehension.

```
val actors: Future[(ActorRef, ActorRef)] = for {
  a <- createActorA()
  b <- createActorB()
} yield (a -> b)
// Await on actors
```

Comment: This has the drawback that the futures run sequentially, unless you create them outside the for-comprehension.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. How can I extract the `ActorRef`s from the `Future`s. The code above just returns another `Future` object.

Comment: Inside the for-comprehension you have `ActorRef` values. You can update the `yield` statement with a block like `yield { val r1: ActorRef = a; val r2: ActorRef = b; /* do what you want with refs */ ??? }`